nan loss in keras when working on a semantic segmentation model to segment brain tumor brats 2021 task 1
some context:
The input has 4 images and i combined them in to 4 channels and the output has 1 images
the input shape is (sample,240,240,4)
output shape: (sample,240,240,1)
The loss of my model for 50 epoch is Nan and the accuracy is too
code:
preprocessing and model structuring
import tensorflow.keras as kr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
#load data
inputimg = np.load('input_dataset.npy')
outputimg = np.load('output_dataset.npy')

inputimg = np.array(inputimg, dtype=np.float32)
outputimg = np.array(outputimg, dtype=np.float32)
outputimg = np.expand_dims(outputimg, axis=3)

x_train = inputimg[:1126].copy()
y_train = outputimg[:1126].copy()
x_train.shape[0] == y_train.shape[0]
x_eval = inputimg[1126:1189].copy()
y_eval = outputimg[1126:1189].copy()
x_test = inputimg[1189:].copy()
y_test = outputimg[1189:].copy()

print("train target:",y_train.shape,"                test target:",y_test.shape)
print(f"train x{x_test.shape}","                test x:", x_test.shape)

#shuffle data
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.shuffle(x_train)
np.random.shuffle(y_train)
np.random.shuffle(x_eval)
np.random.shuffle(y_eval)

np.random.shuffle(x_test)
np.random.shuffle(y_test)



from tensorflow.keras import layers
inputs = kr.Input((240,240,4))
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)

outputs = layers.Conv2D(4, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)
model = kr.Model(inputs,outputs)
model.summary()

#the BRATS 2021 task 1 brain tumour segmentation dataset
#https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/dschettler8845/brats-2021-task1/code?datasetId=1541666&sortBy=voteCount

output of the above
train target: (1126, 240, 240, 1)                 test target: (62, 240, 240, 1)
train x(62, 240, 240, 4)                  test x: (62, 240, 240, 4)
Model: "functional_3"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer_1 (InputLayer)      │ (None, 240, 240, 4)    │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               │ (None, 120, 120, 64)   │         2,368 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               │ (None, 120, 120, 64)   │        36,928 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               │ (None, 60, 60, 128)    │        73,856 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              │ (None, 60, 60, 128)    │       147,584 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              │ (None, 30, 30, 256)    │       295,168 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              │ (None, 30, 30, 256)    │       590,080 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_6              │ (None, 30, 30, 256)    │       590,080 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_7              │ (None, 60, 60, 256)    │       590,080 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_8              │ (None, 60, 60, 128)    │       295,040 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_9              │ (None, 120, 120, 128)  │       147,584 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_10             │ (None, 120, 120, 64)   │        73,792 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_11             │ (None, 240, 240, 64)   │        36,928 │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)               │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              │ (None, 240, 240, 4)    │         2,308 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
 Total params: 2,881,796 (10.99 MB)
 Trainable params: 2,881,796 (10.99 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

when compiling and training:
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")

callbacks = [
    kr.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("help.keras",
                                    save_best_only=True)
]

history = model.fit(inputimg,outputimg,
                    epochs=50,
                    callbacks=callbacks,)

output of compiling and training
Epoch 1/50
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1719246111.166733  116651 service.cc:145] XLA service 0x7f4470003550 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
I0000 00:00:1719246111.169110  116651 service.cc:153]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU, Compute Capability 8.9
2024-06-24 23:21:51.376397: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:268] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
W0000 00:00:1719246111.595718  116651 assert_op.cc:38] Ignoring Assert operator compile_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert
2024-06-24 23:21:51.959587: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:465] Loaded cuDNN version 8907
2024-06-24 23:22:05.935224: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:65] Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,128,121,121]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,128,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, f32[128,128,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 stride=2x2}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convBackwardInput", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
2024-06-24 23:22:06.654590: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:133] The operation took 1.718804966s
Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,128,121,121]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,128,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, f32[128,128,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 stride=2x2}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convBackwardInput", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
2024-06-24 23:22:12.322431: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:65] Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,64,241,241]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,64,120,120]{3,2,1,0}, f32[64,64,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 stride=2x2}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convBackwardInput", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
2024-06-24 23:22:12.953718: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:133] The operation took 1.631474573s
Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,64,241,241]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,64,120,120]{3,2,1,0}, f32[64,64,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 stride=2x2}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convBackwardInput", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
2024-06-24 23:22:33.411114: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:65] Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,256,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,128,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, f32[256,128,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 pad=1_1x1_1}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convForward", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
2024-06-24 23:22:34.596435: E external/local_xla/xla/service/slow_operation_alarm.cc:133] The operation took 2.184202328s
Trying algorithm eng0{} for conv (f32[32,256,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[32,128,60,60]{3,2,1,0}, f32[256,128,3,3]{3,2,1,0}), window={size=3x3 pad=1_1x1_1}, dim_labels=bf01_oi01->bf01, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convForward", backend_config={"operation_queue_id":"0","wait_on_operation_queues":[],"cudnn_conv_backend_config":{"conv_result_scale":1,"activation_mode":"kNone","side_input_scale":0,"leakyrelu_alpha":0}} is taking a while...
I0000 00:00:1719246187.497218  116651 device_compiler.h:188] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
39/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 370ms/step - loss: nan
W0000 00:00:1719246202.227021  116653 assert_op.cc:38] Ignoring Assert operator compile_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 114s 717ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/50
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1719246215.883065  116653 asm_compiler.cc:369] ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function 'input_reduce_select_fusion_7', 188 bytes spill stores, 188 bytes spill loads
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function 'input_compare_reduce_fusion_1', 228 bytes spill stores, 228 bytes spill loads
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function 'input_reduce_select_fusion_9', 200 bytes spill stores, 200 bytes spill loads

/home/red/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py:206: UserWarning: Can save best model only with val_loss available, skipping.
  self._save_model(epoch=epoch, batch=None, logs=logs)
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 342ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 359ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 368ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 361ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 6/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 361ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 7/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 358ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 8/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 362ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 9/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 378ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 10/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 16s 390ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 11/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 16s 397ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 12/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 361ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 13/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 365ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 14/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 359ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 15/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 348ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 16/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 355ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 17/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 355ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 18/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 372ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 19/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 362ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 20/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 344ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 21/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 339ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 22/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 343ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 23/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 341ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 24/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 16s 391ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 25/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 376ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 26/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 16s 392ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 27/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 360ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 28/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 378ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 29/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13s 332ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 30/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 355ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 31/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 381ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 32/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 17s 423ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 33/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19s 485ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 34/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19s 456ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 35/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14s 353ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 36/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 25s 603ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 37/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 368ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 38/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 22s 536ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 39/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15s 382ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 40/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21s 509ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 41/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 201ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 42/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 195ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 43/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8s 194ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 44/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 18s 453ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 45/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 8s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 46/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 195ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 47/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 332ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 48/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 529ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 49/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 402ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 50/50
40/40 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1:00 10s/step - loss: nan


The below shows a blank image when runned
y = inputimg[1]
y = y.reshape(-1, 240, 240, 4)
l = model.predict(y)
mask = np.argmax(l, axis=0)
mask *= 127
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(mask)

I have tried changing the optimizer, losses and the last activation function, moreover my kernel keep crashing for no apparent reason even after changing the batch size.
Now I have tried to use a model from deep learning with python segmentation to see if it fixed the problem, but still loss is nan.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
